# How can I combine multiple scroll event listeners into one?

Tags: javascript, performance, scroll, event-listener

I have the following function that zooms out on images after they enter the viewport. Right now it's attaching as many event listeners as there are elements. For performance reasons I'd like to combine these into one event listener for all elements, but I don't know how. Here is my code:

HTML

```
<div class="image-wrapper"> 
    <div class="image-container elem-1">
        <div class="zoom-images">
            <img class="zoom" src="test" alt="test">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="image-container elem-2">
        <div class="zoom-images">
            <img class="zoom" src="test" alt="test">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="image-container elem-3">
        <div class="zoom-images">
            <img class="zoom" src="test" alt="test">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$('.zoom').each(function() {
    var el = $(this);
    var inViewport = false;
    var isZooming = false;
    originY = 0;
    window.addEventListener('scroll', throttle(zoomImage, 250), {passive: true});
    function zoomImage() {
        originY = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (el.isInViewport()) {
            if (!inViewport) {
                inViewport = true; 
            }
        } else {
            if (inViewport) {
                inViewport = false;
            }
        }   
        if (inViewport) {
            if (!isZooming) {
                window.requestAnimationFrame(function () {
                    el.addClass('is-zooming');
                });
                isZooming = true;
            }
        } else {
            if (isZooming) {
                window.requestAnimationFrame(function () {
                    el.removeClass('is-zooming');
                });
                isZooming = false;
            }
        }
    };
    $.fn.isInViewport = function() {
        var elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
        var elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();
        var viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();
        return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
    };
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks a lot!

Comment: grouping event lestener suppose they all have the same parent and your code don't show  if they are one or not. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'm sorry, I added the HTML now to provide better understanding of the situation. Thank you!

Comment: You can easily move `$.fn.isInViewport` out of the `each`. But where is `throttle` defined? The problem is the closure over `el`.

Comment: I'm using the lodash throttle function. I thought this isn't relevant to the question, that's why I didn't post it here.

Comment: You're probably looking for the [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API). No need to register scroll events at all :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. For anyone who is interested, I solved it like this:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', throttle(check_if_in_view, 220), {
    capture: true,
    passive: true
});
var $animation_elements = $('.zoom-images');
var $window = $(window);
function check_if_in_view() {
    var window_height = $window.height();
    var window_top_position = $window.scrollTop();
    var window_bottom_position = (window_top_position + window_height);
    $.each($animation_elements, function() {
        var $element = $(this);
        var $zoom = $(this).children('img.zoom');
        var element_height = $element.outerHeight();
        var element_top_position = $element.offset().top;
        var element_bottom_position = (element_top_position + element_height);
        if ((element_bottom_position >= window_top_position) &&
            (element_top_position <= window_bottom_position)) {
            requestAnimationFrame( function() {
                $zoom.addClass('is-zooming');
            });
        } else {
            requestAnimationFrame( function() {
                $zoom.removeClass('is-zooming');
            });
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Attach listeners to *containers of* the things of interest and the events will "bubble up" to them.  (The event-call will tell you which object was the target.)

Comment: Could you please provide a short example of what you mean? I'm not sure how the code would look like. Thank you!